# SelectedItem in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="_ComboBoxTemplate" x:Key="_ComboBoxTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ComboBox x:Name="_criteria" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource _ComboBoxTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

In the code behind:

```
this.DataContext = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
```

How do I get it so that the default `SelectedItem` in `ComboBox` is `5`?

Comment: Do you have a VM bound to the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a class containing both your list of items and the selected item:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize it in code behind and set it as `DataContext`:

```
DataContext = new ViewModel
{
    Items = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" },
    SelectedItem = "5"
}
```

Now bind both properties to your `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_criteria" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource _ComboBoxTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

If you set two way binding for `SelectedItem` the value in `DataContext` will even update automatically when the user changes it.

Why did you mention `ObservableCollection` in the title?

Comment: originally, I had _criteria.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Criteria> { new Criteria {...}};
but then changed it over to a string array. Forgot to change the title.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just after you set the DataContext, set `_criteria.SelectedIndex = _criteria.ItemsSource.Count - 1`.

But I'd go with another workaround: reverse the order of the array. That is, `this.DataContext = new string[] { "5", "4", ... }`. "5" would be the first item and you'd keep the order of the list without any other hacks.

Comment: If I try to set the selected index in the xaml for ComboBox, it won't take any values other than -1, so nothing appears by default in the ComboBox

Comment: Not in the XAML but in the code behind. In the XAML, the ComboBox doesn't have any items so you can't select any. But once you've set the DataContext, the ComboBox has items and you can set the desired index.

Comment: ComboBox does have items.  I have them bound by this.DataContext = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }; When I run the program, I see everything in the dropdown menu that I can select.  I want "5" to appear by default. There is no such thing as _criteria.ItemsSource.Count either, so I can't set the index that way.